# Difference between trigger and secondary actor

Tags: uml

Is there any difference between these?

For example, "the engine will start", after the key will be inserted.

From one side, it's clear that the "key inserted" is a trigger.

Does it make the "key" a secondary actor?

Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation of actors, primary and secondary actors at https://blogs.oracle.com/oum/entry/use_case_actors_primary_versus

If we apply this to your example: 
The use case here is 'Start the car'.

An actor is a user OR a (computer) system that interacts with your system (use cases).
A car key is not a user nor is it a system, so it can't be an actor.

The driver is the primary actor. There is not really a secondary actor here.

The triggering of the use case does not seem to matter: the primary actor is the actor to whom the service of the use case is delivered, no matter who triggers the use case or starts the use case.

Another example: 
Suppose that the use case is 'Drive the car'. 
The driver is the primary actor.
Suppose that another person is starting the car, because she always keeps the keys.
Now she is the secondary actor, because she delivers "assistance" to driving the car. Without her starting the car, the use case would never be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger and actor have absolutely different meaning in UML. It cannot be compared.
Trigger represents event that can can be accepted and some reaction in receiving object is performed (for example state changing in StateMachines). Actor, represents external entity which interacts with system during UseCase execution. In pure UML, there are not primary or secondary actors defined as well.

If you need to know how it is defined in UML, I recommend you to read UML superstructure specification. See UseCase and Common Behaviors chapters. You can download free document here: [UML Superstructure](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

Comment: or online http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html vs http://www.uml-diagrams.org/common-behaviors.html#trigger

Answer (score 0):

What about "The driver inserts the key, turns on the car, and the car's engine starts".

The "driver" is the actor, the car's engine & the key are classes / objects.

This is one of ocassions, where a concept can be only mentioned, as a parameter or "primitive type", in this key the key, because, it does not have a lot of operations applied, like the engine, or the driver.